# file parsing using tokens

Tags: java, split, token

I have a text file that reads as follows:

item1, description # brand1, brand2

item2, description # brand3

I have an array list of brands and another array lists of items.

My code reads and assigns everything until it gets to the "#" after the item description...

```
    while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] token = line.split("[,#]+");

            item = token[0];
            description = token[1];

            brand = token[2];

        }
```

How can I get it to properly read what's after the "#" ??
I should mention that an item can belong to 2 or more brands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is regular expressions (regex)

It allows you set up a pattern that defines how the data is structured like this:

```
"(?<item>.+),\s(?<description>.+)\s\#\s(?<brands>.+)"
```

(disclaimer: just a quick example written by hand, might not work correctly)
And then apply the pattern to a string using a matcher.

I'd strongly suggest you read up on regex, or take a tutorial on it. It's super useful.
check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html

Comment: While regular expressions are powerful, there are many file formats that are not regular, and should not be parsed with a regular expression.  Be aware that one should pick the right tool for the job, and always reaching for the regex tool chain means that you will sooner or later be using the wrong tool.  I cringe when I see people doing so much of their "programming" in writing a regex for a something that would be too simple for a regex, or too complex.

Comment: Regex is, however, a way to parse lines of text from a txt file using tokens - which is what was requested. :S

Comment: Agreed, your solution is better in some ways, but it isn't nearly as clear (or safely modifiable).  I love the power of regex, but no tool is best for all environments.  Seems sort of a costly toolkit to just split a line, even if the splitting has sub-splits.

Answer (score 1):

First split by "#" process the result and then by ",".